# Are content creation questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

With the creation of the [Content Creation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50834/content-creation) Area 51 proposal, the question [Isn't this already covered by Web Applications?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9117/40660) was asked. In response, [I suggested](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9120/40660) that looking at the [webapps FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) that all of the proposed questions *should* be on topic here.

The proposer then pointed out that [Question regarding Google Adsense](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18668/10108) was closed as off-topic, refuting my point.

Looking at that question, I can see why it would be closed, but I would have thought *Not a real question* or *Not constructive* would have been better close reasons, as it does fit into my interpretation of [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

So, do people here think that the *Content Creation* proposal should be considered a duplicate of this *webapps* or are the questions there considered off-topic here?

Comment: that's not a very good question to point at.

Comment: @Sathya - Agreed, but it was the counterpoint made to my suggestion. Rather than having an extended argument over on Area 51, I thought it better to bring up the issue here. I'm not a regular on *webapps* so you will all know far better than I whether *Content Creation* questions are on-topic here.

Comment: still trying to understand what "content creation" stands for  - in general, if it's related to use of a webapp for _creating_ content - example - how do I do x, y, z in tumblr, facebook etc - then yes, it is on-topic.

Comment: @Sathya - Yup, that was what I assumed.

Comment: The Content Creation proposal was deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Rubén.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance it certainly does look like it covers topics that are on topic here. SE are usually on the ball with cases like this and will close new site proposals if they are duplicates or subsets of existing sites.

The only difference I can see with the proposal is the line:

> This site aims to help them grow online and produce better content.

To me this implies the site is about how to produce better videos, blog posts etc. which would be largely off topic here. There might be technical questions about formatting of posts etc which would be on topic, but video production and writing questions are definitely off topic.

I see your point about the question you link to. Off topic does seem to be the wrong close reason, but I wasn't involved in the closure so I don't know why that reason was picked. The two community members who did vote to close are highly trusted so I would have picked the same reason they did, so unless the moderator overrode them they probably voted "Off Topic".

Comment: audio/video creation also seems to overlap with [avp.se]

Comment: @Sathya that did cross my mind. There'd also be a potential overlap with [writers.se] for blogs.